# Visualizing raster coverage of PostGIS in OpenJUMP?

Tags: postgis, raster, visualisation, openjump

I am new to **OpenJUMP** and I am trying to use this software for visualizing **PostGIS** **rasters**.

I was able to display vector layers of PostGIS in OpenJUMP but I cannot display raster tables. Do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 3):

First step is to visualize tiles and their unique ID:

```
SELECT rid, rast::geometry
FROM yourRasterTable;
```

Then you can visualise specific tiles and group of pixel values:

```
SELECT (gv).geom, (gv).val
FROM (SELECT ST_DumpAsPolygons(rast) gv
      FROM yourRasterTable
      WHERE rid = XX) foo;
```

You can replace ST_DumpAsPolygons() with ST_PixelAsPolygons() if you don't want pixels to be grouped by common value.

ST_Binary() is not necessary anymore with new versions of OpenJump.

Comment: @milad Did this answer your question? If yes, could you accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

OpenJUMP does not support PostGIS rasters at all as normal raster images. However, it can be used for visualizing vector data that is returned in the Well Known Binary (WKB) format by the PostGIS Raster function ST_AsBinary https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsBinary.html.

There is a tutorial about how OpenJUMP can be used for visualizing PostGIS raster data through the AsBinary route. It is sort of a hack but may be useful for some special needs.

https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRasterTutorial01

OpenJUMP may have changed a bit since the tutorial was written. Today the SQL query tool is in the menu item File - Run Datastore Query.

Comment: It was a good tutorial.
I write it for the people who may read this page after us. This tutorial uses the raster and change it to geom and finally visualize the geometry not the raster.
Thus, As you said I think there is no way to visualize PostGIS raster coverages in OpenJUMP